# Access DataFrameGroupBy object to create single MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I was searching, but I have problems to bring the things together.

The requirement is to get a MultiIndex Dataframe with all given Data. As Index I would like to have the groupby keys.

My dataframe looks like:

```
   A | B | C | D |
1  X   1  hi   ab
2  X   1  hey  ac
3  Z   3  ho   ad
...
```

I cluster by the columns A, B with `dfGrouped = df.groupby(['A','B'])` and get the DataFrameGroupBy object.

To get an overview of the groups I use a loop.

```
 for key,item in dfGrouped: 
       print(key)
       print(item)
```

The output is:

```
(X , 1)
DataFrame of Group
```

But exactly here I have the problem to create a DataFrame with all groups via loop. The key is a tuple and the item is a dataframe. I try to create a MultiIndex DataFrame via Dictionaries, lists and pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples, but it does not work.

The final MultiIndex DataFrame should look like:

```
  Group | Criteria | A | B | C | D
   1      (X,1)      X   1   hi  ab
          (X,1)      X   1   hey ac
   2      (Z,3)      Z   3   ho  ad
```

Is there perhaps an other way to get the required groups?

If you need more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are after so here is my interpretation. I do not think you need to do `groupby`, you can just set the index to your columns `A`, `B` (that I rename for clarity to `id1`, `id2`)

```
df2 = df.set_index(['B','A'],drop=False ).rename_axis(['id1','id2'])
df2
```

this produces:

```
        A   B   C   D
id1 id2             
1   X   X   1   hi  ab
    X   X   1   hey ac
3   Y   Y   3   ho  ad
```

with your index now being MultiIndex (id1,id2)

If you want to add your `Criteria`, `Group` columns you can have them too:

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['Criteria'] = df3.index
group_map = {b:n for n,b in enumerate(df3['B'].unique())}
df3['Group'] = df3['B'].map(group_map)
df3
```

produces

```
            A   B   C   D   Criteria    Group
id1     id2                     
1       X   X   1   hi  ab  (1, X)      0
        X   X   1   hey ac  (1, X)      0
3       Y   Y   3   ho  ad  (3, Y)      1
```

(Here `Group` are just sequentially numbered values from column `B` -- I assumed that's what you wanted). If you want you can `set_index` again to `['Group','A']` if that's what you need

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will follow your idea and come back if it does not fit to my requirement. Nevertheless thank you for your help.